# How can I add a 2nd serial integer key column to a table? (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 8440 records with a natural (string) primary key. Now I just discovered that to support a legacy client, I need the records to have integer keys as well. what's the easiest way to add a serial INT column to this table with a unique constraint and populate it with integer values from 1 to 8440?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the table, add a new not null column of type `serial`, with a unique key on it.

In Postgres, the serial type is a mere alias for the int type with a default value of nextval(some_sequence), the latter of which is created on the fly.

Comment: `NOT NULL UNIQUE` is closer to `PRIMARY KEY`.